# Websphere portal parallel rendering

Tags: parallel-processing, rendering, websphere-portal

We are trying to enable parallel rendering to get lower website homepage load times

However, we constantly get the following error in sys logs

ParallelRende W com.ibm.wps.pe.ext.ppr.ParallelRenderManager createPPRJob EJPPG1132W: Unable to clone request. Parallel rendering will be disabled for this request.

How to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking up the error? Straight from [IBM's doc](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portal/7.0.0/doc/en_us/pt700abd019/html-wrapper-msg.html)

**Explanation**

Your portal setup defines a request wrapper, probably in a servlet filter, which does not support a cloning operation. Parallel portlet rendering cannot work correctly in this configuration.

**User response**

Extend the filter with cloning support, change your portal configuration to remove the filter, or disable parallel portlet rendering.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried implementing cloneable on filter class and wrapper classes. But the error still exists. Getting really crazy